# It appears that with API32+, the contentResolver no longer works for MMS Attachments

Tags: android, mms, android-mms

It appears that with API32, the contentResolver no longer works for MMS Attachments

```
val partURI = Uri.parse("content://mms/part/$partId")
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(partURI)

inputStream?.let { inputStream2 ->
    val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName)
    FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var read: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
    outputStream.flush()
    }
}
inputStream?.close()
```

the attempt to open an InputStream results in an Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: Column _data not found.

Is anyone aware of how to read the data from MMS parts (attachments) with API 33?

In the manifest I have:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

and I dynamically request all the critical permissions:

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post the entire stack trace?